# Start program from terminal tty to desktop session.

Tags: linux, ssh, desktop, tty

I log in a remote computer trought ssh session, this computer is a Desktop computer and it have an user in the desktop, ¿how can i start a program (like skype) in the terminal and starts in the desktop?.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user on the remote desktop computer did a `xhost +` you could try:

```
# in bash, executed on remote computer
DISPLAY=`hostname`:0 skype

# or e.g. in csh:
env DISPLAY=`hostname`:0 skype
```